# How to display data from sqlite in treeview with python

Tags: python, sqlite

i have this class,but when i run this application does not show me anything.. i have seven columns in my table, the header of table appears on my application just data from sqlite doesn't display.. How do i fix this?

```
class Students:
db_name = 'Lutai.db'

def run_query(self, query, parameters = ()):
    with sqlite3.connect (self.db_name) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        query_result = cursor.execute(query,parameters)
        conn.commit()
    return query_result

def viewing_records(self):
    records = self.tree.get_children()
    for element in records:
        self.tree.delete(element)
    query = "SELECT * FROM student ORDER BY nume DESC"
    db_rows = self.run_query(query)
    for row in db_rows:
        self.tree.insert('', 0, text=row[1], values=row[2])
```

my class also contains labels etc photo here:
[image: click here image from imgur.com]

Comment: Does that query actually return a non-empty result? That `nume` in the ORDER BY clause sounds a bit weird, given that your application's language appears to be English. But then again, it might be valid; we simply don't know your table structure. Is that `viewing_records` method actually called anywhere? Are there any Exceptions logged to the PyCharm console when you run that app?

Comment: Side note: I would assume `self.tree.insert('', 0, text=row[1], values=row[2])` to read `self.tree.insert('', 0, text=row[0], values=row[1:])`. Your arguments would lead to the `Nr. Matricol` column to display whatever column gets selected second in a `*` query and `Last Name` would display whatever column gets seletced third. The rest of the columns in your tree would remain empty. It is preferrable to always select the desired columns explicitly in your SQL statement, to make sure that you always get the right columns in the right order.

Comment: @shmee yes it called, i make with Listbox display from database.. here is the call self.viewing_records(), nume this is the name of that column.. it's ok sql statement